# Why const is required when dereferencing std::set<T>::iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, stdset

I have the following code:

```
    std::set< std::vector<int> > testSet;
    vector<int> v0 = vector<int>(3);
    vector<int> v11 = vector<int>(3);
    v0[0] = 0;
    v0[1] = 10;
    v0[2] = 20;
    std::cout << v0[0] << endl;
    testSet.insert(v0);
    v0[0] = 1;
    v0[1] = 11;
    v0[2] = 22;
    testSet.insert(v0);
    std::set< std::vector<int> >::iterator it;

    for (it = testSet.begin(); it != testSet.end(); it++) {
        const std::vector<int>& i = (*it); 
        std::cout << i[0] << endl;  
    }
```

When I change:

```
const std::vector<int>& i = (*it)
```

to:

```
std::vector<int>& i = (*it)
```

it stops working. Apparently `(*it)` returns a `const vector<int>&`, but why is it the case? The set contains vectors, not `const` vectors.

Comment: because any change to vector would break the ordering within set

Comment: Is there any information about this on cppreference? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/
I don't see it.

Comment: First mention is in the second paragraph: `The value of the elements in a set cannot be modified once in the container (the elements are always const)` Then after the member types: `*Note: All iterators in a set point to const elements.` The reason, why it must be so is not elaborated on the site.

Comment: Is there any reason why people answer with comments instead of with *answers*?

Comment: @user107986 the cppreference link would be http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set -- you linked to cplusplus.com

Answer (score 3):

This is because your actual `testSet` declaration looks as follows:

```
std::set<std::vector<int>, std::less<std::vector<int>>> testSet;
//                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

That is, the `value_type` itself is used as the argument for ordering predicate (no matter if it is `std::less<T>` or a custom one), and its location within `std::set` data structure (possibly RB-tree) depends on its *original* value (at the time of `insert` operation).
Thus, changing the content without reordering the `std::set` would break the ordering logic.

The constness of non-const iterator is also mentioned in the standard:

> #### § 23.2.4 Associative containers `[associative.reqmts]`
>
> 6. `iterator` of an associative container is of the bidirectional iterator category. For associative containers where the value type is the same as the key type, both `iterator` and `const_iterator` are constant iterators. It is unspecified whether or not `iterator` and `const_iterator` are the same type.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing a contradictory answer.  The standard is overly presumptuous in saying that changing the object will change the order.  I can easily have an object that itself has constant data that can be used for ordering AND non-constant data that doesn't have anything to do with its order within the set. My objects have a const std::string m_name that is used by my custom comparator for ordering, but has a whole slew of setters for changing other things about it.